# load ajax response data to a page element as inner-html with j query load method

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, jquery

i have a form like this

```
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"  language="javascript">

function get_sub1(value)
{
        $(document).ready(
    function()
    {
    $.post("autofunction.php?action=getsub1" ,
    { navmenu_id : value },
    function(data)
    {   alert(data);
     $('#sub1_menu_td').html(data);
    }); 
    });

}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<form action=""  name="mainform" method="post">

<table align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="1">

<tr> 
<th>Select NavMenu </th>
<td> 
<select id="parent_menu" name="parent_menu"  onchange="get_sub1(this.value)">
<option value="0">Select</option>

<?php 
$nevmenu_result = $db->query ("select * from tblnavmenu");
while ($nevmenu_info = mysql_fetch_array($nevmenu_result))
{
?>


<option value="<?=$nevmenu_info['nevmenu_id']?>" >   <?=$nevmenu_info['nevmenu_name']?> </option>


<?php
}
?>

</select>
</td>

<tr > 
<th>Select Sub1 </th>
<td id="sub1_menu_td"> 
<select id="sub1_menu" name="sub1_menu" >
<option value="0">Select</option>
</select>
</td>

</tr>

<tr> 
<th>Sub2 Code:</th>
<td><input type="text" name="sub2_id" id="sub2_id"  /></td>
</tr>

<tr> 
<th>Sub2 Name:</th>
<td><input type="text" name="sub2_name" id="sub2_name"  /></td>
</tr>


<tr> 
<th>Sub2 Link:</th>
<td><input type="text" name="sub2_link" id="sub2_link"  /></td>
</tr>

</table>


  <table class="button"  align="center">
                   <tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td> <td> <img src="../images/save.png" height="50" width="50" style="cursor:pointer;" alt="Save" onClick="document.mainform.submit();"> </td>
                      </table>  
</form>


</body>
</html>
```

as this form show on the base of  **Select NavMenu**  the  **Select Sub1**  options load which comes from an event which is called on change of  **Select NavMenu** . And the event are defined in which we send value of navmenu and post to **autofunction.php**

**autofunction** code are

```
if($_REQUEST['action'] == "getsub1")
{
$navmenu_id = $_REQUEST['navmenu_id'];

$data = '<select id="sub1_menu" name"sub1_menu"> ';

$navmenu_result = $db->query("select * from sub1 where sub1_nevmenu_id = '".$navmenu_id."' ");
while($navmenu_info = mysql_fetch_array($navmenu_result))
{

$data .= '<option value="' . $navmenu_info['sub1_id'].  '"   > '.$navmenu_info['sub1_name']  . '   </option>      ';

}
$data .= '</select>';
echo $data;

}
```

as this response a select and we change it with previous. Its working goods but problem when i try to get value of **Sub1 select**  to insert in the database. there is no required value because

the content of innerHTML just showing in the browser not in the page source so i search to change content in page source also. i find **j query load**  function. and see a lot of example but fail how to do like

```
$('#sub1_menu_td').load(data); ???????????
```

i need to load **data** into **#sub1_menu_td**.

how to do this.
try a lot like

```
$('#sub1_menu_td').load("autofunction.php #sub1_menu_td");
```

but fail

**My aim is to load same content in pagesource** so i can fetch values

Answer (score 0):

when you use [jquery](http://jquery.com/) and change html of DOM(Document object modal)

then in view source these html which come from (ajax ,load and any method in jquery or javascript) it not seen in view source

in view source we see only which html  come on page load

by server side language like php,,net,java

not by client side language like javascript

see [GOOGLE PLAY](https://play.google.com/store?hl=en)  in this all the html come by ajax see in console for best result see in [firefox](http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/new/)   with [firebug](http://getfirebug.com/)

Comment: i agree "when you use jquery and change html of DOM(Document object modal)

then in view source these html which come from (ajax ,load and any method in jquery or javascript) it not seen in view source

in view source we see only which html come on page load" but my question is how also change in view source the same result as in browser view  ???

Comment: not possible i said in my answer dear by this DOM change and change in dom not come in view source  because when we do view source then view source come as a new page  but in console this come like in firebug if we see in html then we can see our desire change hope it make sense

Comment: dear if i am changing (#sub1_menu_td)  td innerhtml at first when no change event occur its content was `<select id="sub1_menu" name="sub1_menu" >
<option value="0">Select</option>
</select>`

Comment: but if you see in view source then it not show it change in DOM please try to understand any way thanks....

Comment: dear if i am changing (#sub1_menu_td)  td innerhtml at first when no change event occur its content was `<select id="sub1_menu" name="sub1_menu" >
<option value="0">Select</option>
</select>`    when user select from navmenu  and its depening sub1 show in above select by firing onchange event of navmenu select and go to ajax thats do nothing but this `<select id="sub1_menu" name="sub1_menu" >
<option value="0003">item_add</option><option value="0004">item_edit</option>
</select>` so when i do  $code = $_request['sub1_menu'] it gives me zero mean before ajax. not after ajax content not update

Comment: how to get updated values becoz it  taking value from page source not from dom so help me

Answer (score 0):

sorry i can't read all the code, but i see that your autofunction.php need a post variable to work,so in load() method , we add a variable action=getsub1 to verify the condition   **if($_REQUEST['action'] == "getsub1")** :

```
   $('#sub1_menu_td').load("autofunction.php",{action: 'getsub1'});
```

Comment: my ajax working correctly as u see in autofunction.php it gives $data in response which not showing in source page but showing in browser view.So when i want to insert value of select it gives wrong value because in the page source content not change. how to same change occur. its my question .

Comment: try console.log(data) and look at console to see if there is some data or no response

Comment: yes there is response like this `<select id="sub1_menu" name="sub1_menu" > <option value="0003">item_add</option><option value="0004">item_edit</option> </select> `  and according to my code i raplace this code `<select id="sub1_menu" name="sub1_menu" > <option value="0">Select</option> </select>` to reponse data. as mention but when i try to post page and on posting page geting value like $_post['sub1_menu'] . the answer is nothing variable is not set